# JTDS Invalid Parameter index with callable statement

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds

I am getting this exception. But did not found the solution. I have a stored procedure. which accepts 1 input parameter and output is a combination of individual values and list of values. Can anyone help me.

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 11.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.getParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:340)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(JtdsCallableStatement.java:263)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(JtdsCallableStatement.java:251)

I m trying to register the output parameters like this.

```
       private static final String sql2 = "{call dbo.abcc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

        conn = getDBConnection();
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql2);
        cs.setLong(1, 4522366);

        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.CHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.BIT);
        cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);

        cs.registerOutParameter(9, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(10, Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(11, Types.VARCHAR);


        ObjectBean odb = null;
        ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `sql2`?

Comment: This is my database query with stored procedure     


 USE [schema]
GO

DECLARE   return_value int
EXEC  return_value = [dbo].[pr_abcc]
            IAN = 4522366
SELECT      'Return Value' = return_value
GO"

Answer (score 0):

From your example call, your procedure `dbo.abcc` seems to have only 10 parameters, so registering the 11th one fails.